# Setting Config vars visible to os.environ in Jupyter

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, config, amazon-sagemaker

How can I set up a setup file or config.py to set global variables visible to conda environment from within a Jupyter notebook?

If I run a bunch of imports, os.environ will not see them unless I restart, at which point they are lost. I’m working within an EC2 instance and can’t create a persistent config file in directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Sagemaker Notebook, you have a terminal. There you can set in .bashrc export of the variable you need always. Also there are persistent conda Environments.

It is not clear why you say you run a EC2 and still this is tagged as Sagemaker? Do you not have the Sagemaker Notebook service?

Comment: Thanks @zhrist. I have Sagemaker Notebook on EC2 instance. The dir where terminal launches is `/ec2-user/...' and I want to make generalizable for other user. I was able to set os.environ('var') in a loop in setup.py using a separate config variables file. Not sure if this is best way to do it.

Comment: @coder_bob then it seems like a standard setup and you can use the file /home/ec2-user/.bashrc if you run your program after you load the Jupyter. If you want to have the variables before, you can define them in the EC2 creation step ( aws cli or terraform if you use that)